# Is OGG really necessary for HTML5 video full compatibility?

Tags: html, html5-video, flash

I'm preparing a webpage with a video. I'd like to make it compatible with a wide range of devices, so I inserted a HTML5 `<video>` tag with a Flash Player fall-back (FLV video file) for incompatible browsers (mostly Internet Explorer < 9).

For the HTML5 video I converted my video in MP4/H.264 and in WebM/VP8. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video), H.264 is used by:

- Internet Explorer
- Google Chrome
- Safari (iOS+Desktop)
- Android browser

While VP8 is compatible with:

- Firefox
- Opera
- (again) Chrome and Android

It seems that everything is covered (talking about today's last versions of the browsers), with the Flash fall-back for older ones.

Can I skip the OGG version of the video, considering that MP4 + WebM seem to be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for you, but yes, for full compatibility .ogg is required. I tried to create a page in my website for sharing my videos just with h.264 and webM, But lots of smartphones can't play them.

There are many free ogg converters ([one of them as an example](http://download.cnet.com/Free-MP3-WMA-OGG-Converter/3000-2140_4-10793572.html)) available if you need one.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you to tell me an example of a smartphone that is only ogg capable? Just to know if we're talking about older ones?

Comment: If my memory is fine is with a "sony tablet P" and dolphin browser, "Samsung galaxy 551" and Opera Mini, and One Old Lg smartphone ( I don't remember the model), BUt with more popular smartphone, (Nokia Lumia 800, Samsung Galaxy S2, it's work normally...)

Answer (score 1):

h246 covers smartphones and h264 stakeholder browsers (big bad corporations).

WebM covers Firefox and Opera (independent free browsers).

h264 should be the preferred (first) choice, because smartphones may be able to decode WebM, but they usually hardware accelerate only h264.

All browsers which do Theora (ogg) should be also be able to do WebM **nowadays**. There is no reason to encode videos in Theora anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome have had full support of OGG since June 2009 and January 2010, respectively. Firefox first started partially supporting MP4 in April 2013 and Safari and Chrome have had full support for MP4 since 2008 and 2010 or longer. Firefox and Chrome have partially supported WebM since March 2011 and September 2010, respectively. IE fully supports MP4 since March 2011. Edge fully supports MP4 and partially supports WebM. Opera has partially supported WebM since June 2011 and fully supported it since August 2013. All the mobile browsers support MP4, so that's not necessary to include.

So, by only using MP4 and WebM you're supporting Firefox and IE since March 2011, Chrome and Safari since basically forever, and Opera since June 2011. In my opinion, MP4 and WebM give plenty of support. Just include a fallback image and if someone hasn't upgraded their browser for 5 or more years, they don't get the full experience. Sounds fair in my opinion.

If you care to support people who haven't upgraded in 5 years, OGG has very good support in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. IE, Edge, and Safari don't support it at all.